# How much is enough current for this infrared LED?

Tags: voltage, led, current, datasheet

Is 20mA enough to run [this TSAL6400 IR LED?](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81011/tsal6400.pdf)

Could someone teach me how to read these datasheets?

The infrared LEDs will paired with SFH-313A phototransistors to detect the speed of a BB fired from a BB gun.

[image]

Comment: What are you using it for?  Illumination, data transmission...?

Comment: Im using it with a SFH-313A phototransistor to detect a bullet from a BB gun.

Comment: If you shot it from a BB gun, then it is a BB , not a bullet.

Comment: Sorry english is not my first language. Didn't know they were called like that. Im using it with a SFH-313A phototransistor to detect a BB from a BB gun.

Comment: Where are you placing the optics relative to a point on the BB trajectory? Draw a picture.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/uByHJ4R)

Comment: Optical focus of emitted/detected light will play a **major** part in achieving success here...why struggle with infra-red that your eye cannot see? Use a phototransistor that can see red light, and use a red LED light source so you can see what is illuminated. Instead, may I suggest that you shoot through thin strips of conducting foil carrying current to indicated passage of a BB.

Comment: Unless the sensor is very far from the LED, probably less than 1 mA to avoid blinding the sensor. Don't get ahead of yourself, the led current is a free parameter, so set it last once you've designed the optics and receiver electronics and have a better idea how much light is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Figure 6 Radiant Power vs Forward Current. The LED produces 8 mw at a current of 20 ma. You have to decide if this is sufficient for your application.

Comment: How do I know if it is sufficient? Im using it to detect a bullet from a BB gun.

Comment: That is beyond the scope of the datasheet to answer.

Comment: @ToothbrushingIntensifies think about a normal LED (not infrared). You put 20mA through the LED and it lights up really bright. How do you know if it's bright enough? well you just try it and find out.